# How to read value of <std::vector<std::string>> *

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdstring

I pass a `std::vector<std::string>*` to a function where I want to do something with each of the elements with type  `std::string`. My code is the following but I get an error  saying: *terminate called after throwing an instance of std::bad alloc*   **What did I do wrong?**

```
void split_List(std::vector<std::string>* p_completeList) {
    
    std::vector<std::string>* v = new std::vector<std::string>();
    v= p_completeList;

    for(int i = 0; i < v->size(); ++i)
    {
            std::string value = (*v)[i];
            //...do some splitting, printing with value
    }
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code? It will immediately tell you what is wrong. Why are you allocating memory for `v` and then replacing the only pointer to that allocation with `p_completeList`? The allocation is useless and you have a memory leak. Why even use pointers at all?

Comment: why do you allocate a vector just to immediately throw it away? Chances are high that there should be no pointer in this code

Comment: please do not edit the question entirely after you received answers. The code you show will throw a `std::bad_alloc` when you call it often. Thats the issue explained in the given answer. If your issue is something else than what you asked here, ok, it happens, but then you should open a new question. Make sure to include the actual code

Comment: Also not you are uselessly using new. std::vector is NOT polymorphic.  Pass completeList as const &, and initialize your copy with std::vector<std::string> v{completeList};`. The real reason for your crash is you forgot to delete v.  See [avoid use of new/delete](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-newdelete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call this function many many times eventually you will get a `std::bad_alloc` because you are allocations lots of memory that you immediately leak:

```
// dynamically allocate a vector
std::vector<std::string>* v = new std::vector<std::string>();
// now v points to that new vector

// throw away the last reference to the dynamically allocated vector
v= p_completeList;
// now v points to a different vector, the memory is leaked
```

You should not do that. The function can be this:

```
void split_List(std::vector<std::string>* p_completeList) {
    for(int i = 0; i < p_completeList->size(); ++i)
    {
            std::string value = (*p_completeList)[i];
            //...do some splitting, printing with value
    }
 }
```

However, you should pass the vector by reference rather than via raw pointer, also to avoid such confusion as you are facing now. And there is (almost) never a good reason to allocate a `std::vector` via `new`.

Comment: I tried just that but I get the error inside the loop

Comment: @user3443063 then the issue is with `//...do some splitting, printing with value`, I can only help you with code that you show.